# Navbar dropdown Bootstrap not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, include, navbar

I know this has been asked but I can't fix it based on the answers as I've made the includes found in other threads. My dropdown in bootstrap navbar is not working. I find it very odd as other features like the menu for mobile are working. I will join the code below. Thank You!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW" />
<META NAME=“Version” CONTENT=“Plano R1” />
    <title>Plano</title>


    <script src="/scripts/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/scripts/jquery.jeditable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/scripts/jquery.jeditable.masked.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/scripts/jquery.maskedinput-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/scripts/jquery.autocomplete.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/scripts/date.format.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/scripts/jquery.floatThead.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/scripts/PatientSearch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/scripts/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/jquery-ui-latest.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/iPad.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/cms.v2.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/css3-buttons.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/patients.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/appointments.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/jquery.autocomplete.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/css/bootstrap.css">
 <script src="../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <header class="noPrint">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand plano">&nbsp;&nbsp;Plano&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav" role="navigation">
        <li><a href="/agenda/agenda.php"><span class="icon icon33"></span><span class="">Agenda</span></a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">R&eacute;pertoires<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="/providers/">Fournisseurs</a></li>
            <li><a href="/patients/">Patients</a></li>
            <li><a href="/professionals/">Professionels</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/tasks/inactives.php"><span class="icon icon120">T&acirc;ches</a></li>
        <li><a href="/settings/status.php?table=patient"><span class="icon icon96">R&eacute;glages</a></li>
        <li><a href="/patients/dispos.php" onclick="popUp(this.href,'console',600,435);return false;" target="newWin" id="dispo-link">Disponibilit&eacute;s</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="add-link"><span class="icon icon3">Patient</a></li>
        <li><a href="/logout.php"><span class="icon icon151">D&eacute;connexion</a></li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" id="searchboxappointment" name="searchboxappointment" placeholder="Rechercher un patient" class="form-control searchboxappointment searchengine "  size="35" value="<?php  echo isset($_POST['searchboxappointment']) ? $_POST['searchboxappointment'] : "";?>" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

</header
```

Answer (score 2):

Your loading 2 versions of jQuery. Get rid of the 1.11.0 version.

```
 <script src="/scripts/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added your code to a codepen. **[HERE](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wBGoNv)** `li` It seems to be working for me. Perhaps your problem is somewhere else.

Have you checked if those CDN resources are actually providing you with their libraries or even connecting online with your site? Are working off your server in offline mode? If you are, the CDN references will not connect.

I would save those CDN references inside your root. They are great for testing purposes, but they are not meant to be permanent resources. If their server goes down, so will your site. Not to mention, you can't modify the code in them, should you needed to do so.

Comment: I added a codepen in my answer and re-worded the answer as well.

Comment: Please see my edits. The behavior has not changed from my original post.

Comment: user I insist you look into the rest of the code. I updated your code int the codepen I provided and it still works fine. Please check the link in my answer and review

Comment: What could I be looking for in the code? Why does it work on codepen?

Comment: It works in codepen because it is isolated from your site therefore no other script is overwriting it. Check out your page in firefox and use Firebug or inspector to look at the console and it will tell you if you have any errors in your JS. If no errors are there, then deeper debugging is needed. Something that will not be able to be debugged in here because you can't load an entire site here